# How to enable symbolic link in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I enable symbolic link support in my MySQL Server. When I run `show variables like 'have_symlink';` I got result as disabled.

Comment: I've had the same question, but the accepted answer didn't solve mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enable symbolic link then add following line in mysql server configuration file in the section of [mysqld].
    symbolic-links=TRUE
    After adding restart mysql server then you will get show variables like 'have_symlink'; value as YES.